# aapt not found when building new Android app in NetBeans

Tags: android, netbeans, file-not-found, aapt

I just installed NetBeans and the Android SDK following the instructions [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/IntroAndroidDevNetBeans). I am running Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic). NetBeans is 6.7.1. The Android SDK is version 7.

When I try to compile a new project it gives me the following error:

```
Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/oz/android-sdk/platforms/android-7/tools/aapt" (in directory "/home/oz/projects/ArmyBuilder/android"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

When I go into that directory, I see that the file does exist and it has proper permissions to be executable by anyone, yet even bash can't find it!

```
oz@Ivory-Coast:~/android-sdk/platforms/android-7/tools$ pwd
/home/oz/android-sdk/platforms/android-7/tools
oz@Ivory-Coast:~/android-sdk/platforms/android-7/tools$ ls -l
total 4652
-rwxrwxrwx 1 oz oz 3472784 2010-04-20 18:16 aapt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 oz oz 1050336 2010-04-20 18:16 aidl
-rwxrwxrwx 1 oz oz  213698 2010-04-20 18:16 dexdump
-rwxrwxrwx 1 oz oz    2497 2010-04-20 18:16 dx
drwxr-xr-x 2 oz oz    4096 2010-04-20 18:16 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 oz oz   10800 2010-04-20 18:16 NOTICE.txt
oz@Ivory-Coast:~/android-sdk/platforms/android-7/tools$ ./aapt
bash: ./aapt: No such file or directory
oz@Ivory-Coast:~/android-sdk/platforms/android-7/tools$
```

Googling for this error turns up a few other people having this same issue (http://www.mentby.com/erisa/aapt-not-found.html, http://www.helloandroid.com/content/file-not-found-hello-world-application) both with no responses.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is a 64-bit issue, aapt is apparently expecting 32-bit libraries and you have 64-bit libs.

Solution here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1317567

Summary:

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

HTH

Comment: This was a **very** frustrating bug to track down. Thank you for your simple answer.

Comment: If you're having difficulties with travis-ci, see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14392603/82156

Comment: Now i need to install 32 bit OS now ??  OR is there any solution on 64 bit ??